# Tracking user who clicked my link with node.js mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm creating a web app that allows people to adopt pets.

Here is my index.ejs

```
<%- include('partials/header') %>
<div class="row">

  <%  items.forEach(function(items){ %>
<div class="card col-lg-4 col-md-6">

  <img alt="John" style="width:100%" src="data:image/<%=items.img.contentType%>;base64,
                     <%=items.img.data.toString('base64')%>"> 
  <h6><%=items.name%></h6>
  <h6><%=items.dob%></h6>
    <h6><%=items.breed%></h6>
       <h6><%=items.details%></h6>
 
  <p><button>adopt</button></p>
 
        <% }) %>


  </div>
</div>



  <%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

I have a schema

```
const userSchema = {
   email : String,
   password: String,
   name: String
};
```

that saves user credentials when they sign up. WHich redirects them to the page/code(index.ejs) above with a profile card of a pet and an adopt button.

How do I make a post request that logs the user who clicked on the adopt button??

Comment: a button is not a link, either use ajax on the button, or make it a link and track it on the resulting page

Answer (score 0):

```js
// attach click listener to your button
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  // send post request to "/some/endpoint" url
  fetch("/some/endpoint", {
      method: "post",
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      // your post data,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        some: {
          post: "data"
        }
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((text) => console.log("Response text:", text))
    .catch(console.error)
})
```

```html
<button>Adopt</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  i have been able to make some edits. To the best of my understanding, i suppose this parse information from index.ejs but id like to know the user who actually clicked the button. this information isn't on index.ejs page as you only get this page after res.redirect after signing up.

Comment: i could send you my code and you could have a look at it?

Comment: I'd like to have a scenerio whereby once a registered user clicks the adopt button, i can have data sent to admin.ejs showing the full name of the adopter and items.name(pet name ).